# React Native Chrome Debugger not visible in Xcode dev menu

Tags: google-chrome, react-native, xcode7, google-chrome-devtools

i'm searching for about a week for this problem.
I'm using ReactNative v0,26 with Xcode v7.3.1.
If im hitting cmd + D in the simulator it doesn't display "chrome debugger"

What am I missing? I still don't know how to search for this problem...

[screenshot xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3989.png)

Comment: I think `Display Chrome Debugging` has been replaced with `Debug JS Remotely`. What happens when you click on that?

Answer (score 0):

The menu item has been renamed to `Debug JS Remotely`. The default is still Chrome but you can now debug in other IDEs cleanly.